# Combining expand with other operators in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

Let's say I have a set of rewriting rules that I want my Observable to implement:

```
A => B B
B => C
```

That is, whenever there's an `A` on the observable, output two `B`s. Whenever there's a `B` (even when it comes from an `A`), output a `C`. This 
 seems like natural use case for `expand`, and it's [pretty easy to implement](http://rxfiddle.net/#type=editor&code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gZXhwKHgpIHsKICBpZiAoeCA9PSAnQScpIHsKICAgIHJldHVybiBSeC5PYnNlcnZhYmxlLm9mKCdCJywgJ0InKTsKICB9CiAgaWYgKHggPT0gJ0InKSB7CiAgICByZXR1cm4gUnguT2JzZXJ2YWJsZS5vZignQycpOyAgICAKICB9CiAgaWYgKHggPT0gJ0MnKSB7CiAgICByZXR1cm4gUnguT2JzZXJ2YWJsZS5lbXB0eSgpOwogIH0KfQoKUnguT2JzZXJ2YWJsZS5pbnRlcnZhbCgyMDAwKQogIC5tYXBUbygnQScpCiAgLmV4cGFuZChleHApCiAgLnN1YnNjcmliZShjb25zb2xlLmxvZyk7Cg==). As expected, each `A` turns into `ABCBC`.

But what if I want to combine the expansion with another operator? Let's say my rules are:

```
A => B repeated N times, where N is the number of "A"s so far.
B => C, but only if the number of "B"s so far is divisible by 10.
```

Grouping values by whether they're `A`s or `B`s sounds like a job for `groupBy`, and counting the number of outputs for each sounds like `scan`, but how do I combine those operators with `expand`?

Answer (score 0):

Two years late and not strictly an answer to your question, but another approach that yields the same result and might be easier to build upon.

#### Building streams recursively:

This approach builds out your stream recursively. Kind of the same idea you may use to build a nieve parser.

```
function recursiveOperator(){
  return s => s.pipe(
    mergeMap(val => concat(
      of(val),
      streamFor(val)
    ))
  )
}

function streamFor(x){
  let stream;
  if (x == 'A') {
    stream = from(['B','B']);
  }else if (x == 'B') {
    stream = of('C');    
  }else{
    stream = EMPTY;
  }
  return stream.pipe(
    recursiveOperator()
  )
}

zip(
  timer(0, 4000),
  from(['A','B','A'])
).pipe(
  map(([x,y]) => y),
  recursiveOperator()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

output:

```
abcbc // Then wait 4 seconds
bc  // Then wait 4 seconds
abcbc
```

#### Using a Subject:

I'm pretty sure that as-is, this introduces a race condition. They're resolved consistently since JS is single-threaded and the event loop is predictable, but you're having two streams each pushing values to the same subject and I haven't yet built in anything that ensures no unwanted interleaving.

With some tweaking, however, this can be much more performant for large inputs.

```
const valueSubject = new Subject<string>();
valueSubject.subscribe(console.log);

zip(
  timer(0, 4000),
  from(['A', 'B', 'A'])
).pipe(
  map(([x,y]) => y)
).subscribe(val => valueSubject.next(val));

valueSubject.pipe(
  tap(val => {
    if (val == 'A') {
      valueSubject.next('B');
      valueSubject.next('B');
    }else if (val == 'B') {
      valueSubject.next('C');  
    }
  })
).subscribe();
```

output:

```
abcbc // Then wait 4 seconds
bc  // Then wait 4 seconds
abcbc
```